# Azure pipeline will not trigger on tags from Github no matter what

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

In my azure yml trigger I have:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
     - refs/tags/v*
  tags:
    include: ['*']
```

It won't trigger the pipeline on any tag at all, even without the v.

I'm also commiting a small change when testing to make sure that it's not just the YML that's different from the previous deployment.

My code is in an organisation's private github repo and does trigger on branches, but not on tags.

Comment: Remove the tag from the branches, and in the `tags` put `include:` (new line) `- v*`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I tried that too, didn't work :(

Comment: Hi,MichaelB Do you check the option I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Hi Hugh, indeed I have, as well as every variant I can thing of. It just won't work. At this point I don't know if it's a bug with my account or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have since switched to Github Actions just to have everything into one place, wasn't a big fun of the way Azure Pipelines already integrated into Github, non-issue though.

The issue on my side was the way the push was happening from VScode -- it wasn't pushing tags by default, so I ran:

```
git config --global push.followTags true
```

And then from vscode I've started using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to create tags and push with follow tags from that prompt, so that would be:

In order to create the tag:

[image]

And in order to push with the tag:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I test with your yaml sample, there is nothing wrong with the code, it can work well.

[image]
[image]

> does trigger on branches, but not on tags.

From this description, I think the issue could be caused by checking the **Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here** option in Triggers. If you check this option ,the trigger set in yaml will be overwritten here.
[image]

[image]

Comment: this works but then the trigger happens for every commit to the master branch instead of the tags.

Comment: so ehrm, that's it? I should just give up on trying to trigger things on tags with Azure pipelines?

Comment: Hi,MichaelB  No, you don't have to give up, the tag trigger is available in the pipeline. In my answer, I mean don't check the ‘Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here’ option in the classic editor's Triggers. If checked, it may cause the tag trigger in your yaml to fail.

Comment: Lin sorry, I've initially didn't have that 'overried' triggered, I've tried it with the 'override' triggered and to trigger on tags ref as in the YML but that hasn't worked either. I've asked people around on slack and discord and no luck. I don't know if there's something weird with my setup or just a bug but it's not working no matter what...

Comment: Any suggestions on what to investigate/try further regarding this? should I place a support ticket somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for the late response ,you can also place a ticket on our [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) form.There will be other engineers involved.If this is confirmed as a bug, it will be reported to the product group.

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted a thread there: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/803558/cannot-get-my-pipelines-to-trigger-on-tags-only.html